# get name and current value from a check box : react js

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to get the name (name conatins unique ids from  get api  )and current value of check boxes (DefaultChecked contains values "true or false")  when i click on the check box

```
<td style={styles.gridrow}>
                  {this.state.items.map((itm) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <td>
                          <div>
                            {itm.name}
                            <input
                              name={itm.id}
                              type="checkbox"
                              DefaultChecked={itm.taken}
                              onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </>
                    );
                  })}
                </td>
```

when the check box is not checked   and when i click it,  i must get the`itm.id` and `itm.taken` as true

when the check box is   checked   and when i click it,  i must get the`itm.id` and `itm.taken` as false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dataset to get all the values you want on a event

```
<input
    name={itm.id}
    type="checkbox"
    data-name={itm.id}
    data-checked={itm.taken}
    onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
/>
```

You can retrive the data during a event by using

```
function onChange(event) {
const {name,checked} = event.target.dataset; // anything after data- will be the variable name 
if(event.target.checked){
//do something
}eles{
console.log(name,checked);
}
}
```

you can also use `event.target.checked` to see if the checkbox was checked or not and take action accordingly.

Comment: data-checked={itm.taken} does not toggle i wantto recive if it is true when i click check box it must pass false   .here the current value only is being passed

Comment: you can check that by using `event.target.checked` to see if the checkbox was checked or not and take action accordingly.

Comment: DefaultChecked={itm.taken} now always stays as not checked , when i use  data-checked={itm.taken}

Comment: i am suggesting you to use `data-checked` instead of `DefaultChecked`. You can remove `DefaultChecked` now

Comment: i removed it and data is passing correctly but even when i pass the data as checked the ui of the  check box remains uchecked when refreshed

Comment: if you want to make it checked by default just pass a `checked` attribute to input without any value like `<input name={itm.id} type="checkbox" checked />`

Comment: <input name={itm.id} type="checkbox" checked /> made my all check boxes maked as cheked   . i tried this     checked={itm.taken} i made it like this this works the problem i that i have to mannally refresh after i click on a check box inoder it to see the change

Comment: then you have to make it in state